# Trouble with simple clearContent appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am still pretty new to writing javascript and cant figure out whats wrong with my script. I tried to write a script to check the cell in column 10, if the contents of it equal "No" I am trying to make it clear the rest of the cells in that row. For example if "1,10" = "No" it should clear range 1,10 to 1,120. Then I looped it so that it would do this for the rest of the sheet.

The script sort of works. The problem is that it is clearing more rows than it should. Every time the script comes across a single "No" it is clearing the row where no appeared and multiple rows below it even if the column on that row is "Yes".

```js
function fixRemovedChars() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form');
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var i=1;i<rows;i++){
    var range = sheet.getRange(i, 11, i, 110);
    var check = sheet.getRange(i,10).getValue();
    if(check == "No"){
      range.clearContent()
    }
  }
}
```

Please help. I cant figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with my question if someone else is curious. On this line

```
var range = sheet.getRange(i, 11, i, 110);
```

I forgot the syntax is (startrow,startcolumn,number of rows, number of columns).
(#,#,x,#) The x in the example to the left kept increasing, causing it to clear more rows.